# How can i add a Combobox Item to a Xam pagel?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

i am new to XAML and i need to use a Combobox but in my project it seems to not recognize the keyword saying that it was not found.

This is the error im getting:
[image]

How can i solve this?

Comment: XF does not have a native ComboBox control

Comment: But i have seen multiple tutorials using it

Comment: "multiple tutorials" is not helpful.  Maybe if you post a link to a specific one we might be able to help you

Comment: You are right, i was watchin WPF Controls.

Comment: I found "Picker" that does the same

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said in the comments, XF does not have a native Combobox Control.
I found "Picker" to replace it